# map the result I got from api and place the result in accordion using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to map the result I got from api and place the result in accordion using reactjs. When the first button is clicked, all the accordion gets expanded. But I need only one accordion to be expanded and collapsed.

```
<CardBody>
 {result.map(get =>
   <div className="chart-area">
         <Accordion>
            <CollapsibleComponent>
                  <Button  onClick={this.toggle} 
                     style={{ marginBottom:'1rem', width: '1000px', 
                     background: "#419ef9"}}>
                    <span className="glyphicon" >
                    <i className="fa fa-chevron-right normal "></i> 
                     </span>
                    {get.commitMessage},
                      {get.committer},
                      <Moment>{get.commitDate}</Moment>                          
                  </Button>
                  <Collapse isOpen={this.state.collapse}>
                    <Card>
                      <CardBody>
                        {get.added.map(add => (
                          <li>
                            <p>{add}</p>
                          </li>
                        ))}
                        <li>{get.modified}</li>
                      </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                  </Collapse>
                 </CollapsibleComponent>
                </Accordion>
                </div>
              )}
            </CardBody>
```

When the first button is clicked, all the accordion gets expanded. But I need only one accordion to be expanded and collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that all accordion sharing the same flag which shown at

```
<Collapse isOpen={this.state.collapse}>
```

So instead, you need an individual flag for each and every `get` element

Comment: Thanks!!That really helped me.

Comment: @indumaheshwaran: No problem, do remember to mark it as answer if it did answered your question, thanks!